# There is no target type for the collection expression

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, c#-12.0

Using [C# 12's new collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions), I cannot do something like this:

```
if (["blue", "red", "foo"].Any((x) =>
{
    ...
}))
```

It gives a CS9172 compiler error "There is no target type for the collection expression."  Instead of `["blue", "red", "foo"]`, I have to do `new[] { "blue", "red", "foo" }` -- the pre-C# 12 way, which *doesn't* have to specify the type.

Clearly that collection expression contains only one type.  Is there a technical reason why the compiler cannot determine the type?  That would be a very succinct and useful way to use that new feature if it were possible.

Comment: What type do you think it should be?

Comment: The same answer to the question "what type should `new[] { "blue", "red", "foo" }` be?"

Comment: Why should it be an array?  The latter is specifically declared as an array.  The former is *any type of collection*.  If you want an array then *declare an array*.  You already know how to do that.

Comment: Oh so what you're saying is that the vague compiler error is referring to the type of the collection, not the type of what it contains.  I assumed the collection was an array.

Comment: This is how feature was designed. There is no "natural type" for collection expressions (as for quite some time there was none for lambda expressions).

Comment: Great, thank you both.  I think we have the parts for a good answer if one of you wants, because I'm sure I'm not going to be the only person fumbling with this new feature.

Comment: You aren't, and there are similar questions already. The feature is based on collection initializers, (`var x=new List<string>{"a","b","c"}`) and allows writing `List<string> x = ["a","b","c"];`. In both cases the code gets translated to calls to the target's `Add` method.

Comment: The C# language design team is working on this problem. They plan to add a natural type for collection expressions (perhaps in C# 13), so that you could write `var c = [1, 2, 3];`. But there are still open questions. What should this type be and what should it be when you assign it to `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>` etc. ? It could be an array or a `List<T>` or a `Span<T>` or a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` etc. what is the best type?

Comment: I'm at this post because I originally had this `values.Concat(["Any"]).ToArray()` and VS suggested to change it to this `[.. values, .. ["Any"]]` which promptly threw an error. So now I have this `[.. values, .. (string[])["Any"]]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how the feature was designed. There is no "natural type" (at least at the moment) for collection expressions (as for quite some time there was none for lambda expressions). As the doc says:

> A collection expression is a terse syntax that, when evaluated, can be assigned to many different collection types.

If you provide a type the code will compile. For example:

```cs
if (((string[])["blue", "red", "foo"]).Any((x) => true))
{
   ...
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5ZZMAzRACkpXgG0BdAShoCIAjAGwFcBTZgGkTMATtwAm/QSQD2U5o1QBBbAE9KADwaIAvAD5EAFyE8Gm2AG9YiK4lgBfIA)

The conversion rules are defined in the [Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions#conversions) section of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

While what the other answer says is true, there was discussion about giving collection expressions a *contextual* natural type, it just wasn't agreed on what that type should be in all circumstances.

In your case the type you want is `ReadOnlySpan<string>`, not `string[]`, because the former doesn't create a temporary array object for the GC to clean up at a later point for no reason. [Note the difference in IL between the two](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0AZAlgOwI4G5ZZMAzRACkpXgG0BdAShoCIAjAGwFcBTZgGkTMATtwAm/QSQD2U5o1QBBbAE9yAd0QBeAHyINmzYI49mDBolgBvWIlsWYAXyIxSFSgCVuAQ1EB5bOzKAMoADl7YADzU2kxsXLwCwmISzNKy8gCS2KLcAB6+JORxJubahvDmVjZ2sA5AA==), the span version uses a `struct` defined specifically for this collection, and so doesn't allocate any GC objects.